# Distributing an application across Internet

Tags: distributed, .net-remoting

I searched but couldn't find a proper answer for this...may be I didn't look deep enough. Anyways, little insight from you guys will only make things easier. So hear me out.

this is for my final year research project. I just need concepts and if any links I can read more.

So this application is a distributed one for a hotel which has 3 branches (including the main hotel) in location A, B, C.
I & (my colleagues) have developed the database, business logic, and 3 separate GUIs for the billing, bar and the kitchen. All are working perfectly and we used .NET remoting for this. this is the whole system and GUIs connected to the business through LAN.

**This system, should be deployed in each location (A,B,C) and from the main hotel (A), I should be able to view the details of other locations (B,C). and all 3 systems should be connected through the internet.**

problem is, **how do I do that?**

I just wanna view the information of other places and may be take printouts. that is not relevant for the question i guess.

The database is not distributed, each location has its own database. If I were to use a web service, how can I do it more cost-effectively? where do I have to deploy the service?

as a side note, I have developed a simple chat system (remoting) and tried to connect it through internet with a friend but it didn't work. If anyone knows why?

please be kind enough to provide any other relevant information on this topic. and please ask questions.

Comment: You could look into WCF (Windows Communication Foundation). It is THE framework for communication between server and client.

Comment: IS your approach a concrete within the scope of your project or are you able to take another approach at all ?

Comment: @SynerCoder If I develop my server (business tier/layer whatever) using WCF, How can I access it through internet? 
I haven't used WCF before. 

->steve The application must be a standalone one, implementation approach can be any cost effective one. I don't wanna spend a lot on this...as I won't have any revenue except a grade!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just build a web application with a secure login? That way you build one system, deploy one system, maintain one system. All your data would be in one place, making reporting a lot less onerous, the whole thing would be faster and if you ever need to add a fourth, fifth or twenty seventh additional location, then you'd need to do very little to make it happen.

I see no reason why you have to go about it as you are.

Comment: One website for all is the best solution in this case.but unfortunately we can't. :( This is a real world research project we are doing. so what the client wants, we have to give it to them.

Comment: Sounded like a university project from your question. In the real world, sometimes you have to persuade your customer not to throw themselves off a cliff. Customers only know what they want, it is up to you to help them understand what they need.

Comment: ok..If I use a web service, how can I do it while I still have my winforms apps running?